# Как выполнить клик по кнопки если пользователь зашел на сайт с мобильного?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как выполнить авто клик по кнопке если пользователь зашел на сайт с мобильного ? Вот код кнопки :  `<button onclick="hideme(this)" class="close">X - Закрыть эти предложения?</button>`

Comment: node.js - при чем?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".close").click();`

Comment: А где понять что с мобильного ? Размер экрана ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: И как я должен это все в месте сложить ?

Comment: Как нажать на эту кнопку если пользователь зашел с мобильного ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88207/discussion-between-helpsetup-and-igor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") {
  document.querySelector(".close").click();
}
```

```js
if (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") {
  console.log("mobile");
} else {
  console.log("not mobile");
}
```

Comment: undefined Я сюда должен добавить какие устройства или что ?